# Track real time price changes of a token

Tags: raydium, serum

I'd like to track real time price changes of tokens which has pools deployed in Raydium.
It's getting really confusing to be fair, I'm seeing that Raydium uses Serum as an orderbook so technically to track prices i should be using Serum instead?

Am i on the right path?

Comment: Hello. I am also looking for a solution to this issue.

I think I need to use websocket but I don’t know how to configure it

what addresses to monitor to get the necessary data.

do you have any ideas?

thanks